# CSS Accordion + inline-block issue

Tags: menu, slider, accordion, css

I am having a problem with my css accordion menu...

I have creater a nice slider as shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LedZep257/hDzyH/1/

but the lis aren't spaced nicely meaning that some items are not appearing fully.

When I use inline-block, the spacing is right but it mucks up the entire slider:
http://jsfiddle.net/LedZep257/hDzyH/

Can anyone help/does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not set a transition in diferent measures, and I think that "auto" an "%" are diferent measure, you can use only one measure to set the transition, if you are having too much troubles and you really need to get that done why dont you use another measure like "em" meaby that would fix it.

e.g.

```
.horizontalaccordion>ul>li
{
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

list-style: none;
width: 8em; /*I was here*/
height: 40px;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#454545), to(#000000));
transition: width 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.6s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.horizontalaccordion>ul>li>h3
{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
padding-left:19px;
padding-right:18px;
height: 19px;
width: 8em; /*I was here*/
border-left: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999999), to(#cccccc));
white-space: nowrap;
filter: progid;
-ms-filter: progid;
}

.horizontalaccordion>ul>li:hover
{
overflow: hidden;
width: 60em; /*I was here, I just set 60em for example*/
}

.horizontalaccordion:hover li
{

    width: 0em; /*I was here*/
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same problem with the em.
I can only seem to get the li spacing even OR the slider to work effectively and not both. I am slightly at a loss for how I can do this...

Comment: I was not expecting that you still have problems with this, because I test that answer, but I think is related to the measures you are using in the transition.